# Prevent removing overlayed controller from memory when switching tab in UITabView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a TabViewController. It contains a MapViewController with a NavigationItem (title bar with menu items). The MapViewController for itself modally shows another Controller (the settings) which also has a NavigationItem. My problem:

If the settings controller is shown and one switches to another tab and back (the settings controller is still open then) the underlying MapViewController is removed from memory so when the settings controller is dismissed, it shows a black screen where the map controller should be. How can I force to keep the map controller in memory?

- All segues expect from modally "over current context" will cover the TabView, this should not happen, so it has to be a modal segue.
- definesPresentationContext on the MapViewController preserves the map, yes. But when calling the settings controller it is embedded in the map view under the map view navigation item so there are 2 navigation bars. This obviously also mustn't happen.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's being removed from memory?  Are you receiving low memory warnings? Are there no longer any references to it once you switch views?

Comment: There is no memory warning (no apps in use, I' testing on a iPhone 6s, an app here can use as far as I know up to a GB).

Comment: Hi again, I set references to global and statics and checked them at multiple occasions. The references are still present when returning back to the settings controller below which the black screen awaits. So the reference is present.

Comment: I noticed the following: When I return to the tab with the map and there is NO overlying settings controller then the viewDidAppear is executed as one expects. When I return back and the settings controller is opened and I dismiss it, the viewDidAppear from the map is never executed. although the reference to it is never removed. What does that tell me?

Comment: Okay, let's try another approach: If it's to complicated to "keep the view from disappearing" - what code is executed, when I switch from tab to tab? I can manually call this in the viewDidDisappear from the settings controller, can't I?

Comment: I just tested a "rewind segue" from the settings controller back to the map controller beneath instead of "dismiss". Still black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within the modal view. When switching back, the tabbar presented the settings controller but is unable to know from what it was modally called. Define the map view controller as current context and dismiss the navigation bar of the presenting view controller in the viewDidLoad of the upcoming settings controller. When using the setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) it even has a nice look.
The viewWillAppear is a nice place to get it back to place and keep the animations in sync.